# Url changes if i don't pass api parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a common api for search opertaions as well as get operations if the i don't pass the search parameters the URL changes which i don't want.

for eg:
**if search parameter is passed:**
localhost:8080/api/search?name=harmeet

**if no search parameter is passed:**
localhost:8080/api/search

what i want is the url should not change whether i pass the parameter or not

for example **if i don't pass parameter the url should be:**
localhost:8080/api/search?name=''

The code has been written using spring boot

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want this behaviour? Seems pretty sensical to leave it as is.

Comment: So... pass the parameter, and set it to the empty string...

Comment: @JRK due to some requirements I need to to this. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can simply set a default value to avoid that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

What URL gets called is depended on the client-side and not on the server-side. If you always want a parameter value to be something or "" when it is not passed by the client-side, you can define your controller method as:

```
@GetMapping("/api/search")
public Object getName(@Requestparam(value="name",required=false,defaultValue="")String name){
// your logic here
// value of 'name' variable will "" if nothing is passed
}
```

Just set the required field as false and use the defaultValue field to set whatever default value you want to set if the parameter is not provided in the URL call.

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand you want to create API which handle two API calls.

Such as,

http://localhost:8080/search

http://localhost:8080/search?name=hermeet

I supposed you already create API in backend... Right!!!

So, There is not any issue on your logic but parameter which you defined in your method is by default required.

Which don't allow you to pass null or empty value.

You just need to allow your parameter for work with both the cases.
As following ways,

> 1. Optional<'Parameter_Type'> parameter_name
> 2. @RequestParam(value = "parameter_name", required = false)    String variable

**Example :**

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<Entity> getSearchResult(@RequestParam(value = "parameter_name", required = false) String variable) {
   if(variable!=null) { 
      // Get Data based on condition.
   } else {
      // Get All Data
   }
}

@GetMapping("/search")
public List<Entity> getSearchResult(@RequestParam("parameter_name") Optinal<String> variable) {
   if(variable.isPresent()) { 
      // Get Data based on condition.
   } else {
      // Get All Data
   }
}
```